# Fourth link is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click the production cube a popup opens up.

The popup under the image has four links.

But I can see only three links.

How to see the fourth link.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7kx/7/embedded/result/

```
<div class="cubeCellProduction" data-text="Production" data-caption="&lt;a style='padding-left: 30px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' href='/' &gt;Work Orders&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' &gt;Projects&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; 
                    &lt;div&gt;&lt;a style='padding-left: 42px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' &gt; Work Flow &lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt; 
                    &lt;a style='padding-left: 42px; font-size: 14px; color: grey;' &gt;Reports&lt;/a&gt;"
                    data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/Desktop_icons_02.07.13/production.png"></div>

 $('document').ready(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.cubeCellProduction').each(function() {
                    var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
                    $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyleProduction">' + htmlText + '</div>');

                    $(this).hover(

                    function() {

                        $(".cubeTextStyleProduction").addClass("hovered").append("<span class='divStockProduction'>Production</span>");

                    },

                    function() {
                        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
                        $(".cubeTextStyleProduction").removeClass("hovered");

                    });
                });
            }, 600);

        });
```

Comment: `.caption` is set to `height:90px!important`, add another `30px` or so and you should see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.caption` class is set to `height: 90px !important;`. Change to `height: auto;` and that will resolve problem for any number of links.

Answer (score 0):

`.caption`'s `max-height` is preventing the last element from being displayed.

```
.caption { max-height: 90px !important; }
```

The `max-height` needs to be incremented in order to accommodate the hidden element or (ideally) you should use `min-height` and `padding` to achieve the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it might also have something to do with the fact that your second and third link are inside a div, but the first and fourth aren't. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: I did wrap it in a `div` but it didn't change anything, the `CSS` is what is causing the problem.